# Cannot run kotex

Tags: cjk

I try to run:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{default}
}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[cjk]{kotex}

\title[Vortrag]{asdas}

\author{yxc}

\date{xy.\,Oktober 2018}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{(문)}

 \begin{center}  
Test
 \end{center}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But I get the following message:

*Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.log
Sorry, but miktex-makepk did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makepk.log*

miktex-makemf.log:

*2018-09-09 10:58:00,029+0200 INFO  miktex-makemf - starting with command line: miktex-makemf.exe --verbose uwmjbb
...*

Comment: Cannot access my LatexDoe account, so I use a new one. All cjk-related and kotex-related packages are installed according to the MiKTeX package manager. What can I do?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! It works fine for me. - 1. Could you run any other small test document? 2. Have you checked all packages?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by choosing the complete installation option of MiKTeX.

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).